# Sorting JTable Rows manually and with TableRowSorter simultaneously

Tags: java, sorting, jtable

I have to create a table that can be sorted by clicking on the table header AND by reordering single and multiple rows by hand.

I made some buttons to move selected rows in the table model up, down, to the top or bottom. Those buttons alter the table model and afterwards update the JTable.
This alone works fine.

But when I start sorting the rows by clicking on the columns in the table header everything goes wrong.
The manual sorting works with the collection in the table model, the sorting by clicking the header works with some kind of table view.

Is there a way to move the rows manually only in the table view and not in the table models collection?
Or is there an other even better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) API addresses the relationship between model and view co-ordinates with respect to sorting. In particular, it says, "In the examples area, there is a demonstration of a sorting algorithm making use of exactly this technique to interpose yet another coordinate system where the order of the rows is changed, rather than the order of the columns." You might compare what you're doing with the relevant example in [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: i could have done it that way but it would still be a confusing and weird way to sort my table so i decided to take a different approach to gui.

Comment: @Justus1: I tend to agree; consistent results will make the most sense to the user.